# PostgreSQL Query Not Returning Rows for Current Month

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL version: 14.10

I'm facing an issue with a PostgreSQL SQL query that aims to retrieve records from the partner_online_time table for the current month. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM partner_online_time
WHERE TRIM(month) = TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month');
```

Despite having confirmed that TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month') correctly returns the expected month name (November in my case), this query doesn't return any rows. I have records in the partner_online_time table for November.

Here is a sample of the records in partner_online_time for November:

```
id  | restaurant_drn |  month   | year | online_mins 
----+----------------+----------+------+------------
  8 | Restaurant2    | November | 2023 |         180 
  9 | Restaurant3    | November | 2023 |         210
```

What could be the issue with my PostgreSQL query, and how can I modify it to retrieve the desired records?

Comment: `select trim(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')) = 'November'; t`. To question add: 1) Postgres version. 2) Client and version. 3) Result of `length(month) ... trim(month) = 'November'`.

Comment: Aah, I see the problem you put the `trim` on the column when it should be on `TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')` as per [Data formating functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html): *Month  full capitalized month name (blank-padded to 9 chars)*. So it is returning `'November '` which you are comparing to I'm guessing `'November'`.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. This fixes the issue.(Added the final query in the question)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add the solution to the question, or to add SOLVED. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer] for details.

Comment: @KenWhite, the link is not valid. It should be https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Yeah, I must have a mismatched set of square brackets that broke it. That's the link I used. If you hover the mouse pointer over it and look in the browser status bar, you can see the trailing ] that doesn't seem to have a match at the front. Thanks for catching it - I type those links often enough that I don't usually check for errors any more. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the comparison of month names, where TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month') returned a value with trailing spaces ('November '). To resolve this, the query was adjusted to apply LOWER and TRIM functions to both sides of the comparison, ensuring consistent case and removing any leading or trailing spaces. The corrected query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM partner_online_time WHERE LOWER(TRIM(month)) = LOWER(TRIM(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')));
```

Appreciations to @adrianklaver for pointing out the formatting issue!

Answer (score 0):

By default, PostgreSQL is case-sensitive when compared. So shouldn't be the query like this

```
WHERE LOWER(TRIM(month)) = LOWER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month'));
```

Here I believe that you don't have any trailing/leading spaces in your column

Comment: Did try this, it did not work

Comment: `select TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month'); November` returns case matching values so that is not the issue per `select trim(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')) = 'November'; t`. Either update answer to one that applies or delete it.